# Как получить статус платежа (киви кошелек)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qiwi

Всем привет. Делаю вроде правильно, но получаю всё время только один ответ статуса платежа WATING

```
new_bill = p2p.bill(amount=1, lifetime=30, comment='Комментарий..') # Выставление счета, сумма, жизнь ссылки = 30 минут, коммент
print(new_bill.status)
```

Оплачиваю для теста с помощью сбер. карты, успешно, но статус не меняется на PAID. Как получить ответ PAID? Что не так? Вывод последней истории платежа не вариант. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было всего лишь добавить кнопку, с помощью которой проверять статус:)

Comment: какую конкретно? оставьте более развернутый ответ

Comment: Любую, чтобы ловить статус платежа                                                                                              ``                                                                                                                                                      
```if  'Проверить' in text: #Проверка статуса выставленного счета
        bill_status = text.split('Проверить_')[-1] 
        if bill_status == "PAID":
            print('fsddssf')      
```